# Show the automatic "low quality" flags in the moderator queue after they have been first visible to the 10K queue for a while

Tags: feature-request, flagging, moderator-tools

Moderators see the automatic "low quality" flags immediately after they are generated. Those flags are for posts that don't pass an automatic check about the quality of the post.
Alone, the flag doesn't have a particular meaning; it could apply to effective answers, to comments written as answer, or non sense. If the post is deleted, it is not deleted because the automatic flag, but because it is a comment written as answer, a different short question written as answer, spam, or non sense.

As such, it would be better if those automatic "low quality" flags would be first visible to 10K users, and to moderators (after X hours), if none of the 10K users took an action.